# How to run a jar file with mpi on linux

Tags: java, maven, jar, mpi

I have a java program, and it uses MPI. If it's a single file, I can use mpijavac to compile it and use mpirun/mpiexec to run, but it's a maven file on IDEA, and I package it to a jar file.

when I run it on Linux using
`mpirun java -jar xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -np 4`
it shows
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mpi/MPI`, just on code `MPI.Init(args);`

mpi version: `openmpi-4.1.1`.

this is my pom.xml

```
     <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.txt</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib</directory>=
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    .......
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>8</source>
            <target>8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <compilerArguments>
                <extdirs>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib</extdirs>
            </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

And it can compile and package successfully. How can i run a mpi-java-jar program on linux, thanks for your solution!

Comment: IIRC, you need to explicitly append the Open MPI jar file if you specify the `-jar` option.

Comment: thanks! It's useful to this problem